# Do you think people can be more nice about correcting you?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Me, being a new user, accidentally posted a coding question on programmers.stackexchange that asked how something could be done when I should have posted it on Stack Overflow.

This was an honest mistake. Granted I probably could have read through the sites rules first but with all the different Stack sites I thought I was posting on the same site (Stack Overflow) where I had asked questions before.

About 15 minutes after someone comments "This question is BLATANTLY off topic and completely goes against what programmers.stackexchange is about." This user did not curse me out or tell me anything super rude but to be honest whenever I log on to this site I never feel in a "friendly" environment. Maybe the user could've more politely corrected me by saying something along the lines of "You seem to be new but direct coding question should be posted on Stack Overflow" or something like that because I am probably not the only who feels this way but people seem to be sort of rude on here.

Any thoughts on this because it has been getting under my skin lately with people being so rude to new users or questions that need to be fixed.

Comment: The frustration occurs because new users routinely ask their first new question on a Stack Exchange site without ever bothering to find out the first thing about how the site works.

Comment: As I said in my post it was an honest mistake because I thought I was posting on the same site I had previously posted on (Stack Overflow)

Comment: Programmers doesn't even look remotely like Stack Overflow; you didn't notice the change in the color scheme?

Comment: As stated above, AGAIN, I am a NEW user so in fact I did not. This kind of attitude towards users is exactly what I am talking about

Comment: Checking your account history, it would appear that you don't have an account to Programmers that's linked to this account, so it's clearly apparent that you got lost, despite the fact that you've [successfully posted four questions and three answers to Stack Overflow.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3597090/user3597090)  You didn't notice something was wrong when it suddenly asked you to log in on Programmers?

Comment: Like I said, I am a new user so NO I did not. This is exactly what I am talking about. If I were to see a question that belonged somewhere else I wouldn't get all bent of shape but would probably POLITELY tell the user where it should be posted.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Good argument for "should have noticed" not a good excuse for people being rude though. People make mistakes, its usually enough punishment to publicly inform them of the mistake.

Comment: @AaronLS I totally agree maybe I should have payed more attention or read through the site rules but I admitted to this mistake. But like you said I do not think it should allow people to rudely comment

Comment: Note that programmers has it's own meta where this probably should be asked instead. I kinda agree that Gnat's (canned) comments are a bit on the harsh side, but he's more likely to see your thoughts about them on Meta.programmers.stackexchange.com than here. Oh, the irony.

Comment: Haha I see where you are coming from @MartijnPieters and I do see the irony lol :P the only reason I posted it on here is because it happens on here pretty frequently as well lol trust me I understand the differences between the sites now

Comment: @Martijn: Sorta knew it was Gnat.  I'll have a discussion with him.

Comment: I can't see the [programmers.se] post in question, but based off of what was mentioned, I'd be pretty upset about that kind of response too (although I also understand the frustration of experienced users, but that's still not an excuse). I've actually been guilty of some pretty blunt and less than tactful responses as well (I wanted to apologize to one guy here on Meta, but he already deleted his post before I could). Human beings aren't perfect, even moderators, and we all make mistakes. There's actually a [Meta Stack Exchange post about it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92066/163250).

Comment: Yeah I deleted the post because I realized it was on the wrong site and wanted to avoid any further problems but yeah for sure man no one is perfect, like myself I admitted to my mistake of posting on the wrong site.

Comment: See also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZRUaDGW7WQ

Comment: @RobertHarvey HAHAHAHA! Pretty please with sugar on top clean the f******* car hahaha!

Comment: Do you have any alternate wording suggestions for how to tell a user who posts a debugging/implementation code question on P.SE (or a 'how do I fix my computer' question on Stack Overflow) that they are very much in the wrong place? Realizing that asking the question means they've completely skipped over the [about](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/about) page that shows up with the 'Don't ask about...' section and likely need to be pointed to that again.

Comment: @MichaelT Well, removing the all-caps "BLATANTLY" would be a good start...

Comment: question is not **[about]** Stack Overflow - belongs to [Programmers meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/) (where it would possibly be closed as a duplicate of [Summer of Love and questions that the FAQ says should not be asked](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3959/summer-of-love-and-questions-that-the-faq-says-should-not-be-asked))

Comment: @RobertHarvey the question at Programmers is likely this one: [How to make Entry Boxes interact w/ each other in Python IDLE Tkinter?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/238861/how-to-make-entry-boxes-interact-w-each-other-in-python-idle-tkinter) - deleted by OP, and in comments they brag about it being **[cross-posted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is strictly frowned upon...'")** "I did ask on Stack Overflow"

Comment: I assumed gnat was a moderator, but it appears I was mistaken. I think it's just because I see him linking to related questions all the time here on Meta and [meta.se].

Comment: @BenAaronson it appears that the OP should have included the text 'emphases added' when copying it here.  The original text can be seen at: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jfPlh.png .  The full text of the cross posted question can be seen at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23618694/ .  Note that there is often a different message when we see that the OP *has* cross posted the question to warn others about the futility of migrating the question. As an aside, it would help if the OP had merged the account http://stackoverflow.com/users/3528395/user3528395 - this may reduce future problems.

Comment: @MichaelT Ah, fair enough!

Comment: @BenAaronson for the sake of completeness, links in the comment shown at the [screen shot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jfPlh.png) are **[about](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/about "Programmers about page")** and http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: ....So OP claims he didn't know he was on a different site despite in comments claiming he had cross-posted on both sites. When quoting he chooses to exclude all advice that gnat gave to him, adding ALL CAPS to the only potentially "unkind" word in the mix........

Comment: @OGHaza per my reading, [commented post](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jfPlh.png) was an [utter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/utter), [outright](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outright), [flagrant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flagrant), [glaring](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glaring) off-topic, totally ignoring what Programmers is **[about](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/about)**

Comment: Yes emphasis was added to "blatantly" to show the word choice, I dont know maybe I am to sensitive but it seems like there could've been a better way to get his message across

Comment: @zzirrgrizz It probably would have been better to do a screen capture of all of the comments instead to make sure that everything is properly understood and there is no misrepresentation. Do you have a suggestion for an alternate adverb? The key concepts to get across are that this is stated in the [about](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/about) page and that there is significant disapproval of either cross posting questions or posting questions that, if the "Don't ask about" section was read would immediately preclude the question - "Don't ask about implementation issues and coding tools"

Comment: @RobertHarvey Generally speaking, your answers are a great example of how NOT to develop UI. Instead of focusing on correcting the user, it would be more constructive to think of a way how to deal with such a misfired question. Why not have a features which allows users to vote to move a question to another site and admins to do the move easily.

Comment: @Tymek: We already have that; it's called *migration.*  It's very limited in scope because so many people do it so badly.  A better solution is for the OP to manage this themselves; a migration is quite straightforward if you simply post the question on the correct site, and delete it from the incorrect one.  Not sure what you mean by bad UI.

Answer (score 7):

I'm still pretty new myself, but from what I've seen there's probably a combination of two factors leading to people taking a harsh or unfriendly tone with new users:

**An emotional reaction caused by genuine frustration.**

Most likely fuelled by one or more of:

- seeing the same things over and over from many users (I think inappropriate questions are a sore spot on Programmers for example)
- the idea that askers are implicitly expecting quite a lot of effort from people to provide free help with their problems, and the perception that their mistake indicates they're not willing to put in even minimal effort in return
- viewing the mistake as one small symptom of a (perceived) larger downward trend on the site which they despair over

**A deliberate decision to try to reform or put off 'bad' users**

This is not an emotional reaction but an intellectual belief that harsh comments are an effective way at encouraging users to either shape up (learn the rules better, be more careful or take more time with their next post) or ship out (if they're stupid or lazy enough that they'll never be a positive contribution to the site).

As far as I'm concerned, the first reason is more of a mitigating factor or excuse than an actual justifying reason. Everybody's human, but I think not getting angry and snapping at people for purely emotional reasons is something we can at least aspire to.

As for the second reason, well people will probably have different opinions on whether this is really effective. To my mind it's completely counterproductive. The kind of homework-posting, question-duplicating, help-center-not-reading user who this is supposed to discourage is already demonstrating that they don't care about what other people on the site think about them, so why would they be put off by an unfriendly tone? Whereas people who are (at least potentially) willing to put the effort are the ones who care about making a positive contribution, and so are much more likely to be put off by unnecessary hostility, or encouraged by friendly guidance.

Comment: I agree that there's no excuse for rude comments, no matter how frustrated you are. There's a very fine line between being non-rudely to-the-point, and being rudely blunt.

Comment: @Cupcake Perfectly stated man!

Comment: One of the challenges that may also be entering this a bit of [culture clash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-_and_low-context_cultures) between high and low context cultures.  Northern US and German, Dutch, and Scandinavian cultures don't place as significant emphasis on word choice. While French, Spanish, Indian, and Asian cultures can be highly sensitive to word choice. This can affect the amount of perceived hostility/guidance in a given sentence.

Answer (score 2):

People are and will always be **people**. Yes, some users are much more friendly than others, some really want to help you a lot even understanding where/how should you ask your questions and are more pro-newbies (as you and me).

While other users cannot accept people who asks questions that they think aren't appropriate to this site, so they try to get you scared and with this approach *their goal is that you will be more careful* when posting again.

But in the end, most users are looking forward to make StackExchange(and its sites) a better place and with questions/answers that are meaningful enough that a user getting here by the first time will **find the solution for his problem** and be ***interested in participating in such site***.

Comment: I totally agree with you users should be trying to make Stack Exchange better, no doubt! But I just feel like people could be a little more polite while doing it in order to make new users feel more welcome and not like they're stupid haha.

Comment: @user3597090: You weren't here before the [Summer of Love](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/) occurred.  It's paradise now compared to the way it was then.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I feel like we could use a new Summer of Love. There's too much confrontation involved with downvote/close-vote/delete-votes. What if we adopted a different signal-to-noise system that didn't involve such emotionally charged forms of feedback?

Comment: @Cupcake, absolutely. Let's have a Winter of Hate, so we can bury the noise our beloved signal is drowning in.