# Why do we not have an off-topic flag for closing as off-topic?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, close-reasons

This applies mostly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975647/counter-strike-source-zombie-riot-config), but can obviously be applied to many other situations.

In case it's closed:

> I currently have a CSS server running and it works great, but I want
>   to enable Zombie riot (game where you survive against waves of
>   zombies) ... I think I have all the files but I don't know how to turn
>   it on... If you could help we can discuss teamviewer over Skype

Why do we not have a flag under the "off-topic" menu that is simply "off-topic"? These are the current options:

[image]

Only...at least for this question, the question has nothing to do with programming *at all* and doesn't really fit on any SE  network. So, shouldn't there be an off-topic close reason for being generally "off-topic"? A nicer way to phrase it would be "This question appears to be off-topic because **it doesn't fall within the specifications for any current site in the Stack Exchange network**".

Is that unreasonable, or is there something about SE policy that I'm missing? Other sites have more generalized off-topic reasons, but those are generally sites that are more subjective than SO.

**Related**: [Flagging off-topic questions for low-rep users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253799/flagging-off-topic-questions-for-low-rep-users?rq=1)

Comment: Doesn't happen that often but always annoys me as well that we need to type a custom reason for blatantly out of scope stuff. "This question is off topic because it is about gardening" or whatever.

Comment: I think the point is that a general "off-topic" provides virtually no feedback to the user except that the question isn't welcome.  By forcing users to select an appropriate close reason or type a custom reason, the **hope** is the asker will at least get some feedback better than "go away".

Comment: @psubsee2003 But while `it doesn't fall within the specifications for any current site in the Stack Exchange network` probably isn't very helpful to the user, isn't it the truth? Is there a better way to phrase that?

Comment: @AstroCB cases where a question can't be made acceptable for at least one site in the SE family these days should be extremely rare.  The very few cases where it would apply wouldn't justify the lazy uses that would come up.  Many will see the generic reason as an excuse to close any questions that doesn't fit the other close reasons

Comment: "it doesn't fall within the specifications for any current site in the Stack Exchange network" - we have over hundred sites (AFAIK) - are there enough people that knows exactly what's on topic on each to justify having such a reason? Is it useful to indicate that a question doesn't fit **anywhere**, as opposed to **here** - communities are fairly isolated. By the way - there is [gaming.se] - my guess is, if that question fits anywhere, it would be there (although probably not in its current state). [se] isn't just about programming - there are plenty of other sites.

Comment: Similarly related was [this recent question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254628/flag-declined-a-moderator-reviewed-your-flag-but-found-no-evidence-to-support), as the two cases which prompted it had been too low-quality to move to any other SE site. The advice given there was that low-rep users such as myself should simply down-vote and hope that enough people will do the same that it'll get auto-deleted. It does seem to be a recurring theme, though.

Comment: The "cascading stylesheet server" had me wondering.... then I realized what was going on.

Comment: I have encountered this exact problem before, so +1. In addition, for the Spam flag, `This question is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional.` doesn't cover cases where it's simply pure spam. Not an ad, not a promo, just _spam_.

Comment: This has been discussed *many* times on the global Meta. It seems no one is listening. Users who *want* to help clean up crap cannot reasonably do so. And they wonder why the site is in decline.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Funny how the ones with privileges aren't exercising them more than the people without them have a desire to.

Comment: @BoltClock I don't know understand what that means. In my experience, they are. Although it does get rather fatiguing. You can only keep it up for so long without a break. Without the diamond, a feeling of helplessness sets in.

Comment: @CodyGray I do find it interesting, though, that at least there is discussion about it if nothing more...I will say that I have seen a few occasions in short time here where questions are simply not fit for a Q/A format, so it's not like they can just be pointed to another site, because they'll just be rejected there as well. This question, for example, would almost certainly be closed within ten minutes on Arqade even though it fits the subject of that site.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As you noted, this has come up a number of times over the past year. [Back then, I stated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185867/no-custom-off-topic-message-when-flagging-on-so/185873#185873):

> We'll revisit the need for a low-rep user "other" option based on usage, but initially we're trying to restrict the use of flag-to-close to problems that are generally agreed-on by the community.

I think we've had long enough to observe this now.

The original design for this dialog had an "other" option that would prompt for and then generate a comment. We restricted this to *voters* out of concern that flaggers are often confused themselves as to what is on- or off-topic: generating a comment in response to a flag that may well be declined or ignored entirely is just noise.

Frankly, the comments generated even by *voters* have been a mixed bag. Some are helpful and educational, many simply state the obvious, some are down-right rude. Expanding this to include comments from folks with even *less* experience moderating does not seem like a great idea either.

The most common scenario where flaggers are frustrated by the lack of a general-purpose off-topic option involves questions that are *blatantly* off-topic. Therefore, the obvious solution is... to just make that an option:

[image: Other (question is blatantly off-topic)]

Any question thus flagged will eventually appear in [/review/close](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/), with the default off-topic reason shown but not selectable in the close dialog. Thus, when this flag is reviewed, anyone *voting* to close it would still need to either provide a comment or choose one of the predefined options. For questions that *aren't* off-topic, no additional noise will be generated.

Comment: Rolled out in 6 to 8 weeks?

Comment: Will this be anywhere?

Comment: did you consider using word other than "blatant" there, [there were complaints asking for nicer words](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254623/do-you-think-people-can-be-more-nice-about-correcting-you "example"). Words like "utter", "outright", "flagrant", "glaring" could probably be just as accurate

Comment: "Obvious" would probably work, @gnat.

Comment: I think "blatantly" is the more appropriate word to use here -- we want to tell flaggers that the question has to be quite poor to use that option.

Comment: Indeed, @Qantas - and so that's what we went with.

Comment: Though I see why you've done this, it's just going to cause more arguments in the "what course should I take next" and "does the licence cover this thing" questions. Could you make it more "off topic according to the help centre" like to cover the stuff that people think _is_ programming?

Comment: The reason shown in the screenshot above is only for people *flagging*, @Ben - it won't actually appear to the folks who *wrote* the question. If/when the question is eventually *closed*, a more specific reason will need to be provided.

Comment: Is this only available on Stack Overflow for now? I imagine the word "programming" would have to be substituted on a per-site basis otherwise.

Comment: It's available [everywhere](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185867/no-custom-off-topic-message-when-flagging-on-so/185873#185873) @Bolt. The topic is drawn from site settings.

Comment: Oh, right. "This question does not appear to be about <topic>, within the scope defined in the help center."

Comment: This was changed again today? I find it hard to keep track of which close reasons are available and *why*. I don't want to have to search through the meta hoping I will find a post explaining the changes, are these changes listed somewhere or something?

Comment: So are we eventually going to get this off-topic reason for regular close votes?

Comment: You already do, @Sam - it's called "other". The complaint here was that *flaggers* had no "other" option, which was the case because I *really* didn't want folks without the privilege to close running around saying things were off-topic without someone a bit more experienced to review those assertions first.