# How do I flag a question that's essentially looking for a contractor?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537452/test-the-security-bugs-of-my-website-html-php-sql#24537452) seems to be looking for a penetration tester to test an application for free. My first thought for a flag reason was "off-site library/resource", but does that apply if OP isn't looking for a testing tool, but a human tester? Or is it off-topic enough to be "blatantly off-topic"? Question text:

> Is there a way to test the vulnerabilities of my website,
>
> like users passwords privacy, sql database, php etc?
>
> I am not an hacker, and I don't know how to find vulnerabilities, like
>   hacks, injections etc
>
> I'd like to find a generous hacker who wants to test the security
>   level... :)
>
> Actually I have no important personal contents, so, if something goes
>   wrong, there is no problem for me

Comment: @Payeli: And which one should that be? Custom?

Comment: @Deduplicator I assume they mean "Flagging>Closing>Off-Topic>Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with programming)"

Comment: @Michelle: [Seems I don't get that.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eq1iV.png) But I won't bounty away all my rep just to recover it.

Comment: @Deduplicator http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/257935/839601

Comment: @gnat I was aware of the close reason, just not sure how off-topic is blatantly off-topic, and more not sure whether it fell under resource recommendation.

Comment: @Michelle http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - per my reading, "blatantly" matches perfectly here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion (and that's just mine), the question you referenced seems like a good fit for the relatively new "blatantly off-topic" flag that I [requested last month](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257883/why-do-we-not-have-an-off-topic-flag-for-closing-as-off-topic).

It literally has *nothing* to do with programming and should be flagged as such.

Just like a CSS server with zombies.

Comment: Having taken a step back for a few hours before thinking about it again, you're right. Guess I'm just second-guessing myself because it's new? I do appreciate it for the _really_ clear-cut cases with nary a program or programmer involved, though.

Comment: @Michelle I understand what you're thinking: I haven't used it yet myself and I'm reluctant to suggest it whenever it comes up here on Meta because I think it's a really powerful flag that I don't want to be taken lightly or overused.