# Closing an off-topic question that is not on-topic anywhere

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, scope

Given a question such as "Which IPod should I buy?" (actually seen today, with no further details), which reason should be chosen for closing?

The question is obviously off-topic. The following close reason fits almost exactly

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic
>   for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily
>   for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

However the last sentence is problematic. The OP will certainly not get any help on SuperUser. Certain questions about iPods may be on-topic there, but certainly not this one. This much is obvious to anyone glancing at the help section of that site, but since the OP posted this question here, it is likely they will post it again over there without a second thought.

So, what reason should be chosen for questions which are predominantly off-topic, but which are, even ignoring that fact, so bad that there is no point in asking it anywhere else?

Is it appropriate to select a custom reason and enter "this is simply off-topic"?

(In this particular case I entered a custom close reason, but the question was ultimately closed with the "Super User" reason, presumably because the first part fits so well. I am a little uncomfortable with my name as one of the closing votes associated with such a recommendation to ask again over there)

Comment: There's another question of "why are there two close reasons that *look* like migration reasons (SU is an existing path)". Questions with those reasons should either be migrated via close or flagged for migration rather than given a "closed here, repost over there" style close reason.  I'm sure there are good other reasons the community can think of to take their place.

Comment: If you didn't have close vote privileges, and were just *flagging* the question, you would use [this option](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/257935/366904). I have no idea why they insist on us doing extra work just because we have full close vote privileges. "Blatantly off-topic" is distressingly common, in my experience.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it appropriate to select a custom reason and enter "this is simply offtopic"?

That's exactly what you should do.

I have the same problem as you with the other close reason. I don't think we should be mentioning Super User there at all. Unfortunately I can't edit the reason only replace it and I don't want to do that.

Comment: Not "blatantly off-topic" or VLQ? Seems like they'd both cover that question nicely...

Comment: @JonK blatantly off topic is the proper choice for the flag for those less than 3k rep.  Those who have close votes can write custom reasons and don't have the blatantly off topic flag reason.  VLQ would be chancy as a flag and there are arguments for and against such a flag (personally, I agree that it has sever content problems and unlikely to be salvageable through editing).