# What to do with questions about a Physics program that has nothing to do with coding?

Tags: discussion, flags, scope

I just saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699716/bounce-ball-on-moving-paddle-to-create-effect) question that had some correct code with some calculations in it. Now, the question has to do with the program, but it is more physics than implementation. I think this question would rather fit on [physics.stackexchange.com](http://physics.stackexchange.com) or similar sites and not here.

I clicked on the "flag" link under the question and choosed "Off-Topic", but I can't decide what to click now. It has to do with programming, so its not blatantly off-topic, and I can't say that it belongs to physics.stackexchange.com. What should I do with questions like that?

To clarify my question: I don't want the question to be migrated, I just want the question to be closed as Off-Topic, but I can't find a suitable option for do so. An option like "This question is about Physics, you might get help on physics.stackexchange.com" or similar would be the thing I want to do with the question. Then, the OP can decide if he want to ask the question, edited so that it fits into the rules, on physics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You should leave a comment that this question is off topic and should be asked at physics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: That question is a little bit broad ("...but I have no idea how to do it."), but it is not off-topic. He's asking about how to implement a feature in his code, not the physics of the problem.

Comment: @BilltheLizard But he also asks for the physics behind it - he didn't wrote "you could calculate it like this: a=b" or something like this

Comment: I don't believe the OP is looking for a "real world" physics solution. Mark, in his sample code, the lack of adjustment for friction, elasticity, momentum, and energy transfer loss. He appears to be looking for a "convincing" fix only.

Comment: If it has to be moved (which I'm not convinced of), Game Development might be a better target. I agree with @Jongware, I don't think this is about an accurate physical calculation. Game developers are experts at making physical effects look good while keeping the calculations as simple as possible.

Comment: I did find a Game Dev answer (no duplicate; concerning the basics only), but several topically related "pure" SO questions as well. I am inclined to state it's indeed a Game Dev question, not a particular *programming* (or physics) problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go to Flagging > Closing > Off-Topic > Migration, you are presented with a list of sites to flag for migration to, which includes the per-site Meta and the top four sites for migration from that particular site:

[image: Migration]

If the site that you would like to recommend migration for is not in that list, you should use a custom flag and *fully* explain why you think that the specific question should be migrated. More often than not, questions are not worth migrating because they would just be closed and/or deleted on the target site, but there are a few gems for which migration is ideal.

Even then, make sure you fully explain your reasoning, because I've had a few migration flags declined for reasons that are unclear and have had to ping mods in chat to get them migrated.

I should also note that I agree with Brad Larson in that this question in particular should probably not be migrated, because it is technically on-topic here.

Comment: Sure, but how do I use a custom flag? There is no option "belongs on another site" or something like this

Comment: @msrd0 It should be `Flagging > other (needs moderator ♦ attention)` (it's the last option on the first flag menu). You don't need a specific categorization for your flag as long as you specify that you want it to be migrated.

Comment: But this'll be waste of moderators♦ time. Why can't I add my own explanation why it is off-topic? I never say I would have migrated it since they might not understand the program code he wrote, but a new question on physics.SE and the one on SO closed as OT is the thing I would do

Comment: @msrd0 It doesn't matter how you flag it: only moderators can migrate questions.

Comment: As I already said, I don't want to migrate the question, I want the question to be closed as OT on SO - the OP then might ask his question, edited so that it fit on Physics, there

Comment: @msrd0 That is highly discouraged: the reason we have migration is to *prevent* cross-posting. If you want it re-asked there, edit it here and flag it for migration. Otherwise, just close it here as blatantly off-topic (not about programming *within the scope defined by the Help Center), because that's [what the flag is for](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257883/why-do-we-not-have-an-off-topic-flag-for-closing-as-off-topic).

Answer (score 7):

I see no reason to close that question, or to move it offsite. It's a question involving specific code, where they can't figure out how to modify that code to achieve a specific result.

Just because the answer might be rooted in physics doesn't immediately make it off topic for Stack Overflow. We have many code-related questions that involve physics, math, or other concepts that have received great answers (almost all of them using employing specific code for those concepts).

There are much worse questions to be closed before this one.