# Could a question asking about a lack of reply from LinkedIn have been salvaged by editing?

Tags: discussion, scope, low-quality-posts, declined-flags, outsourcing

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117936/no-reply-from-linkedin-for-partnership-program) (now deleted) as Very Low Quality because I couldn't see any way it could be fixed by editing:

> We have applied to LinkedIn API partnership program, its been 20 days,
>   still we doesn't received any reply from them.
>
> Any suggestions on the next steps.

My flag was declined with

> VLQ should be for items that can't be salvaged by an edit. Make sure
>   the post falls is VLQ otherwise use standard close votes/flags.

In the end the post was closed then deleted through the normal channels, but VLQ would have done it quicker (and I hoped with less total effort) and I thought that was what it was for.

I realise moderators make occasional mistakes with flags and I'm fine if that's all that happened here.

But in case it wasn't a mistake I just wanted to check if I'm missing something about how this question could have been salvaged or was using the flag incorrectly for some other reason.

Comment: While I don't disagree the question should be closed and deleted (the faster the better), a close vote seems sufficient here. If you simply flagged it because you wanted it to be deleted faster, that feels like an invalid reason for bothering a mod.

Comment: I thought there was a review queue for VLQ? I was hoping that it could be deleted with less total effort by flagging it, given that it seemed like a clear-cut case.

Comment: There is a rewiew queue for close votes as well. Why is that not sufficient? VLQ has a stricter definition than "this is off topic for SO".

Comment: Yes, and I thought this question clearly met that definition: "items that can't be salvaged by an edit".

Comment: editing wouldn't help, see: **[Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/839601)**. Funny guy who declined your flag probably believes that proper formatting and grammar make product support request less [blatantly off-topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/257935/839601)

Comment: I was assuming that it was just a mistake, but wanted to check.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288387/289086 - note that if this type of flag response is given from the Help & Improvement Queue, that may have problems.

Comment: Just like with the occasional moderator flags being declined despite being valid, mistakes do happen. The question is deleted now, just move on.

Comment: @AndréDaniel: That's not the point; OP is trying to figure out when he would ever flag something as VLQ.

Comment: extremely related [Under the new triage system, when and how should moderators act on "very low quality" flags on questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288450)

Answer (score -5):

VLQ is for posts that do not fall under one of the *other* flag/vote categories, and yet are so worthless that they should be deleted.

For questions that seem bad, here's a decision tree.

1. Spam or offensive?  Flag.
2. Off topic?  No-continue; Yes-Vote to Close.
3. Too broad/unclear?  No-Continue; Yes-Vote to close or edit to improve.
4. Technically a valid question, but horribly written/formatted?  Edit.

VLQ would be extremely rare for questions (to the point I don't mention it here) because almost all of the time either it's not a valid question or it's fixable.  It's so easy to close questions that are not very good that using the flag is a waste of time.

For answers that seem bad it's a shorter decision tree since you have fewer options.

1. Spam or offensive? Flag.
2. Not an answer?  No-continue; Yes-Flag.
3. An answer you disagree with or think was written poorly?  No-continue; Yes-Downvote.
4. Technically an answer, but incoherent to the point of being useless and not salvageable?  VLQ.  This should be rare, though, most of these are simply downvoted.  NOT based on the technical content of the answer.

Comment: Do you have a reference for it only being for things that don't fall under another category? FWIW closing things isn't actually particularly easy on many lightly used tags.